# why does my array not show embedding dimensionality?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have an array `arr` that looks like this:

```
array([array([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.24531606, 0.        , 0.10192551, 0.26281643, 0.07157524,
       0.        , 0.20981437, 0.2868098 , 0.        , 0.1088962 ,
       0.18332416, 0.03177325, 0.07842019, 0.3699289 , 0.07368854,
       0.81981325, 0.        , 0.        , 0.31003478, 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.02403858, 0.        , 0.5475581 , 0.4329713 ,
       0.0179123 , 0.29171306, 0.        , 0.        , 0.30288118,
       0.3583041 , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.13133994, 0.        , 0.1786428 , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.07417253, 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.4042313 , 0.11129653, 0.19236773, 0.        ,
       0.2960508 , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.2696649 ,
       0.        , 0.66468614, 0.        , 0.33312002, 0.37111816,
       0.        , 0.25402874, 0.        , 0.44765374, 0.17118327,
       0.3711421 , 0.34410077, 0.        , 0.32523516, 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.1903065 , 0.01348885,
       0.41701746, 0.16775154, 0.22308391, 0.        , 0.43001148,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.16873305, 0.07424918, 0.8382288 , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.40988386, 0.        , 0.1286441 ],
      dtype=float32),
       array([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.08070941,
       0.21275514, 0.        , 0.12470831, 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.15967356,
       0.        , 0.125227  , 0.        , 0.54971164, 0.3698824 ,
       0.50047994, 0.01577441, 0.        , 0.35907358, 0.05245908,
       0.        , 0.03381306, 0.        , 0.20995654, 0.33167285,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.2612371 ,
       0.27756646, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.34772083, 0.        , 0.07980645, 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.12616262, 0.05151966, 0.34031492, 0.16197157, 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.32765007, 0.43190247, 0.4834022 , 0.        ,
       0.16961017, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.4300272 ,
       0.        , 0.52864766, 0.        , 0.54931706, 0.0083029 ,
       0.        , 0.17301333, 0.        , 0.5219162 , 0.4499495 ,
       0.53348315, 0.30723187, 0.039416  , 0.4131335 , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.11425531, 0.37206763, 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.10734618, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.33719772,
       0.        , 0.30729622, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.05175096, 0.06109752, 0.52779436, 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.08292301, 0.        , 0.        ],
      dtype=float32),
       array([0.00000000e+00, 5.62019534e-02, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       7.19960481e-02, 0.00000000e+00, 3.65110308e-01, 1.21489525e-01,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.21438891e-01, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 5.91379702e-02,
       0.00000000e+00, 7.50079229e-02, 4.28686321e-01, 5.64703345e-02,
       1.78176463e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       1.40424430e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.74734205e-01, 2.95386076e-01,
       0.00000000e+00, 2.55320162e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       2.34026015e-01, 3.07884991e-01, 1.81427911e-01, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 2.81380445e-01, 1.37542844e-01, 2.18648076e-01,
       3.85622919e-01, 1.25074089e-02, 0.00000000e+00, 1.24475770e-02,
       1.00661419e-01, 5.22997439e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 2.94359863e-01,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 3.22944015e-01, 1.79439157e-01, 3.41101974e-01,
       2.13420063e-01, 1.57576442e-01, 1.46742716e-01, 0.00000000e+00,
       1.62984639e-01, 3.54695588e-01, 4.00077850e-01, 4.96700048e-01,
       0.00000000e+00, 1.04978859e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.24490447e-01,
       1.87058702e-01, 4.02200446e-02, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       2.56456316e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       2.41882682e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 5.26796393e-02, 0.00000000e+00,
       1.08238049e-02, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 4.87089157e-04,
       3.22218329e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 1.06772654e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 9.88138989e-02],
      dtype=float32)], dtype=object)
```

When I run `arr.shape`, the output is `(3,)`.

However, I want it to output `(3,100)`, as each array within the array is shape `(100,)`.

Comment: Pasting your code, I get `arr.shape` as `(3,100)` like you want. But the `dtype=object` is suspicious. How are you constructing this array?

Comment: This kind of thing should usually be fixed earlier, at the point where you created the array, not in post-processing. It tends to indicate the presence of earlier bugs.

Comment: This array contains 3 arrays.  What's the shapes of those 3?  If they are all the same, `np.stack` could be used to join them.

Comment: When I do a copy-n-paste of the array, I get a (3,100) array, not this nested object dtype.  So the subarrays do match in size, and `np.stack` will join them.  Some how you constructed them as an object dtype with separate arrays.  That's not easy to do accidentally.